# transition height not working on div with overflow hidden and fixed height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a little notification tab within my website which I would like to slide out when the trigger is clicked.

I've added some **jQuery** which sets the height of the `div` to 336px. However, the transition does not want to work.

But, when I go into inspect element within chrome and manually change the pixel values, the transition works how it should.

The following is my **jQuery**:

```
if(trigger.hasClass(open)){
    $("#user-logged-in__dropdown-panel").css("display", "block");
    $("#user-logged-in__dropdown-panel").css("height", "336px");
} else {
    $("#user-logged-in__dropdown-panel").css("height", "0px");
    $("#user-logged-in__dropdown-panel").css("display", "none");
}
```

My **HTML**:

```
<div id="user-logged-in__dropdown-panel">
    <div class="navigation__logged-in-user__dropdown-panel">
        <!-- content !-->     
    </div>
</div>
```

and my **CSS**:

```
#user-logged-in__dropdown-panel{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    right: -2px;
    width: 323px;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden; /* gives slideout effect */
    transition: height 250ms;
}
.navigation__logged-in-user__dropdown-panel{
    position: relative;
    top: 14px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
}
.navigation__logged-in-user__dropdown-panel:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    right: -1px;
    width: 127px;
    height: 13px;
}
```

I have double checked that the transition attribute is correct, along with all of my **jQuery**. But, it still doesn't work.

All help is appreciated :)

**EDIT**: I managed to get the transition to work for a moment by removing `display: none` from `#user-logged-in__dropdown-panel` within my **CSS**. However, when the trigger is clicked again (and it adds the `display` attribute to it again), it goes back to the way it was before.

Comment: Show us the fiddle for this, the current code you provided is not appropriate.

Comment: @SauravRastogi sure :) one sec

Comment: Where's the fiddle?

Comment: I'm having trouble creating it. For some reason, codepen and jsfiddle don't want to recognise jQuery :/

Comment: @Caelan. You give me the link without adding jquery.

Comment: @Caelan. Try my answer :) please notify me if it's working or not.

Comment: @LaraBelle please check the new edit

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a couple of methods that facilitates or does drop down feature.
The following Snippet uses `.toggle()`, details are commented in Snippet.

**SNIPPET**

```js
/* Delegate click event to #btn1...
|  ...call the .toggle method on...
|  ...navPanel to hide and show...
|  ...at a slow duration
*/
$('#btn1').on('click', function() {
  $('.navPanel').toggle('slow');
});
```

```css
.navPanel {
  display: none;
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  border: 3px ridge #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btn1'>Click</button>
<div class="navPanel">
  <p>XXXXXXXXX</p>
  <p>XXXXXXXXXX</p>
  <p>XXXXXXXX</p>
  <p>XXXXXXXXX</p>
</div>
```

Off the top of my head here are some more methods that you could use:

- `slide*`

  - `*Up()`
  - `*Down()`
  - `*Toggle()`
- `fade*`

  - `*In()`
  - `*Out()`
  - `*Toggle()`
  - `*To()`
- `hide()`
- `show()`

The asterisk denotes a prefix`*` or `*`suffix ex. `fadeIn()` `slideDown()`